# Mongodb $lookup with nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I am trying to create a join using mongo's lookup. I have these three collections.

orderTracking

```
{   
    _id: ObejctId("59fb7815b3b8429f4750b0df"),
    itemName : "Hamam Soap",
    TrackLocation: [{locationId: 1, at:"2017-10-11"},
            {locationId: 2,at:"2017-10-13"}],
    userId : 12,
    price: 20
}
```

locationType

```
{
    _id: ObejctId("59b2111345cb72345a35fefd"),
    locationId : 1
    productTypeName: "Warehouse"
},{
    _id: ObejctId("59af8ce445cb72345a35feea"),
    locationId : 2
    productTypeName: "On Transit"
}
```

User

```
{
    _id: ObejctId("59a504eb6171b554c02292a9"),
            "user ID":12,
    "userName" : "Shahabaz Shafi",
    "dateOfBirth" : "1992-01-01",
    "addres": {
        "country" : "India",
        "state" : "Karnataka",
        "city" :  "Bengaluru"
    }

}
```

and trying to flatten this to this kind of output.

```
{
"userName" : "Shahabaz Shafi",
"userId":12,
"dateOfBirth" : "1992-01-01",
"country" : "India",
"state" : "Karnataka",
"city" :  "Bengaluru"

"locationType" : [ {productTypeName: "Warehouse",at:"2017-10-11"}, {productTypeName: "On Transit",at:"2017-10-13"}]
}
```

Edit: 15-11-2018 Updated output

Made some changes to the output columns

```
{
   "userName":"Shahabaz Shafi",
   "userId":12,
   "dateOfBirth":"1992-01-01",
   "country":"India",
   "state":"Karnataka",
   "city":"Bengaluru",
   "items":[
      {
         "itemName":"Hamam Soap",
         "userId":12,
         "price":20,
         "TrackLocation":[
            {
               "locationId":1,
               "at":"2017-10-11",
               "productTypeName":"Warehouse"
            },
            {
               "locationId":2,
               "at":"2017-10-13",
               "productTypeName":"On Transit"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I approach this ?

PS : I am also using compass

Comment: Orders TrackLocation.locationId is looked up with locationType's locationId then again Orders userId is looked up with Users userId column. I had missed user id column previously in user table now I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.User.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "orderTracking",
    "let": { "userId": "$userId" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$userId", "$$userId"] }}},
      { "$unwind": "$TrackLocation" },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "locationType",
        "let": { "location": "$TrackLocation.locationId" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$locationId", "$$location"] }}}
        ],
        "as": "locationType"
      }},
      { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "productTypeName": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$locationType.productTypeName", 0] },
        "at": "$TrackLocation.at"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "locationType"
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$addres", "$$ROOT"] }}},
  { "$project": { "addres": 0 }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dfu5CEZCgkJ)

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("59a504eb6171b554c02292a9"),
    "city": "Bengaluru",
    "country": "India",
    "dateOfBirth": "1992-01-01",
    "locationType": [
      {
        "at": "2017-10-11",
        "productTypeName": "Warehouse"
      },
      {
        "at": "2017-10-13",
        "productTypeName": "On Transit"
      }
    ],
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "userId": 12,
    "userName": "Shahabaz Shafi"
  }
]
```

Comment: I am getting 
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5bed1d5a61e4044a7cedcb89"), "userId" : 12, "userName" : "Shahabaz Shafi", "dateOfBirth" : "1992-01-01", "address" : { "country" : "India", "state" : "karnataka", "city" : "bengaluru" }, "locationType" : [ { "at" : ISODate("2017-10-10T18:30:00Z") } ] }    

I Just ran the same query, The rest of the values are missing from this query did I miss anything?

Comment: Please check the output in the link. I have posted your collections and ran the query. It works perfect.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine you are a star. I had some issues with the syntax when I tried adding a few columns at the end. I am somehow struggling to get ItemName and price of the same I tried adding them to the final project step but it repeats twice, How do I get only once?  I have updated the output.

Comment: You didn't update your question with the sample collection. You just updated it with  the sample output. How can't produce the expected output. And also it will be better if you ask a new question and accept the above one.

Comment: The expected output can't be produced is it? In general i should be able to add all the "orderTracking" columns to the output this would answer my question.

Comment: You are asking totally different question. Please ask a new question with the sample documents and the output. I will surely answer you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183738/discussion-between-shahabaz-and-anthony-winzlet).